# Запрет открытия 2-х окон

Tags: c#, .net

Как можно запретить открытие двух окон на C#?

Comment: если просто тупо прочитать вопрос, то большинство поймет его так: Как не разрешать человеку открывать более одного окна программы  VS C# 2010.При чем именно вижуал студио, а не программы написанной на вижуал студио.
Может вы имели в виду именно программу, написаную на вижуал студио? 
И может не второе окно, а множественный запуск одного приложения?

Если так, то вот хорошая статья на эту тему

http://skillcoding.com/Default.aspx?id=89

Answer (score 2):

На основе Mutex'а

```
 string id = "GUID...";

 using (NamedMutex nm = new NamedMutex(false, id))
 {
    if (!nm.WaitOne(0, false))
    {
       return;
    }
    // ...
 }
```

Либо используя пространство имен Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices - там есть специальные возможности для этого.

Comment: Ага спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Программист должен сам управлять в каких случаях какие окна будут активны / неактивны поеазани или скрытые, для этого есть соответствующие методы что-то типа SetVisible и SetActive.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам необходимо вывести не более одного диалогового окна определенного типа в MDI, то Вы можете использовать паттерн Одиночка (Singelton) в классе формы. Если же Вам необходимо запустить не более одного экземпляра Вашей программы, то используйте Mutex.

Comment: Єсли же Вам необходимо запустить неболее одного екземпляра Вашей программи то используйте Mutex.


Вот именно это, а где его надо использовать?

Comment: В самом начале работы программы проверяете есть ли в системе занятый мьютекс, если он есть то завершаете программу иначе создаете мьютекс и занимаете его